# Verificar se data está entre duas datas no intervalo de 30 min

Tags: java, spring-boot, data, timestamp

Eu tenho um serviço que antes de salvar algum valor no banco, é preciso ser verificado se ele está dentro de algum período já salvo no banco. Cada período é composto por meia hora.
ex:

```
10:00
10:30
11:00
```

Se o usuario tentar colocar 10:31, uma exceção deve ser disparada.
O meu service está pronto e toda a lógica implementada, porém eu queria ajuda para entender porque não está entrando no `if` quando eu envio a mesma data 2 vezes ou por ex 10:31.

```
@Service
public class CalendarService {

@Autowired
private CalendarRepository calendarRepository;

public Calendar create(Calendar calendar)
{
    calendar.setId(null);
    checkSlotBetweenDate(calendar);
    addThirtyMinutes(calendar);
    calendar.setName("Crane");

    return calendarRepository.save(calendar);
}

public void addThirtyMinutes(Calendar calendar)
{
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(calendar.getStartTime());
    cal.add(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.setEndTime(cal.getTime());
}

public void checkSlotBetweenDate(Calendar calendar)
{
    Iterable<Calendar> cal = calendarRepository.findAll();

    for(Calendar key: cal)
    {
        System.out.println(calendar.getStartTime()+ " Enviado por mim ");
        System.out.println(convertTime(key.getStartTime())+ " Dt inicio e fim do Banco  " +convertTime(key.getEndTime()));
        if(convertTime(key.getStartTime()).after(calendar.getStartTime()) && convertTime(key.getEndTime()).before(calendar.getStartTime()))
        {
            throw new BadRequestException("O período selecionado já está ocupado!");
        }
    }
}

public Date convertTime(Date date) 
{    
    java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();  
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal.getTime(); 
}
}
```

Já tentei diversos `if`'s, mas nada cair na exceção. Como por exemplo:

```
if (key.getStartTime().getTime() >= calendar.getStartTime().getTime()
    && key.getEndTime().getTime() <= calendar.getStartTime().getTime())
```

No console é impresso:

```
Mon May 07 20:00:00 BRT 2018 Enviado por mim 
Mon May 07 20:00:00 BRT 2018 Dt inicio e fim do Banco  Mon May 07 20:30:00 BRT 2018
```

E de fato, era pra cair na exceção pois as datas são iguais.
Peço ajuda nessa lógica e caso alguém tenha uma outra lógica ou sugestão, por favor, me diga.

Comment: Não entendi bem a lógica. Se os períodos são 10:00, 10:30 e 11:00, só deve aceitar esses horários? (por isso 10:31 não é aceito?) E no seu exemplo, os horários são 20:00 e 20:30, não estou entendendo quais são os critérios para aceitar um valor como válido ou lançar exceção.
Outro detalhe é que o método `convertTime` não está convertendo nada (compare o valor de `date.getTime()` antes e depois do método e veja que na verdade ele não muda nada - melhor, veja que `convertTime(date).equals(date)` retorna true, ou seja, o método está retornando outro `Date` com o mesmo valor)

Comment: Esses 10:00, 10:30 e 11:00 foi só um exemplo. A regra seria assim, se eu fizer um cadastro as 10:30, o sistema irá adicionar + 30 min e fara com que esse horário fique indisponível para um outro cadastro. Em outras palavras, de 10:30 até 11:00 não é possivel cadastrar + nd dentro desse intervalo, exemplo seria 10:31. Sem o convertTime a data estava num formato +/- assim: "2018-05-07T20:31:00" e ai dava erro no If, por conta disso tive que usar esse recurso. Conseguiu entender a lógica agr, amigo?

Comment: Peguei aqui, sem o convertTime retorna 2018-05-07 20:00:00.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseado [no seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297657/verificar-se-data-est%C3%A1-entre-duas-datas-no-intervalo-de-30-min?noredirect=1#comment604733_297657), você só precisa pegar a data do cadastro, somar 30 minutos e por fim comparar a data do novo cadastro com o intervalo obtido.

No caso, o seu método para adicionar 30 minutos está correto. Eu só mudaria o nome da sua classe, porque ter 2 classes chamada `Calendar` pode confundir um pouco (eu mesmo demorei para entender no seu código que são 2 classes diferentes).

De qualquer forma, supondo que você tem 2 instâncias de `java.util.Calendar`, sendo que o fim é 30 minutos depois do início, e uma outra instância que você quer verificar se está dentro do intervalo, a comparação fica assim:

```
// todas são java.util.Calendar
Calendar inicio = // data de inicio
Calendar fim = // 30 minutos depois do início

Calendar cal = // data que eu quero testar

if (cal.before(inicio) || cal.after(fim)) {
    // cal está fora do intervalo
} else {
    // cal está dentro do intervalo
}
```

Resumindo, se a data em questão é anterior ao início, ou posterior ao fim, então está fora do intervalo e portanto pode ser cadastrada. Caso contrário, está dentro do intervalo e não pode ser cadastrada.

Se você estiver trabalhando com `java.util.Date`, ela também possui os métodos `after` e `before` e a lógica é a mesma.

---

**Obs**: o seu método `convertTime` faz um `cal.setTime(date);` para logo em seguida retornar `cal.getTime()`, ou seja está retornando a mesma data que recebeu (na prática, é como se o método não fizesse nenhuma conversão, pois retorna um `Date` com o mesmo valor que recebeu).

### java.time

Caso seja possível alterar suas classes, eu sugiro usar a API `java.time`, disponível a partir do Java 8. Se você usa Java 6 ou 7, é possível usar o [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), que possui as mesmas classes do `java.time`, a única diferença é que no backport as classes estão no pacote `org.threeten.bp`.

Para saber o momento exato em que algo é feito, você pode usar a classe `Instant`. Esta API é bem mais amigável e menos confusa que `Date` e `Calendar`, e o código ficaria assim:

```
// data/hora atual
Instant inicio = Instant.now();
// 30 minutos depois
Instant fim = inicio.plus(30, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

Instant instant = // data/hora que quero comparar

if (instant.isBefore(inicio) || instant.isAfter(fim)) {
    // fora do intervalo
} else {
    // dentro do intervalo
}
```

Caso você precise trabalhar com `Date`, é possível converter facilmente. A única diferença é que no Java 8 existem métodos próprios para isso na classe `Date`:

```
// converter para java.util.Date
Date date = Date.from(instant);
// converter para java.time.Instant
Instant inst = date.toInstant();
```

Enquanto no ThreeTen Backport você deve usar a classe `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils`:

```
// converter para java.util.Date
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(instant);
// converter para org.threeten.bp.Instant
Instant inst = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(date);
```

Comment: Realmente eu vacilei chamando a entidade de Calendar rs mas d qq forma, mt obgd pela resposta. Eu organizei o código e resolvi com esse if(selectedDate.after(convertTime(start)) && selectedDate.before(convertTime(end))). Eu vou marcar como resolvido pq alem da sua resposta ser mt boa, me ajudou mt a entender o meu erro. A única coisa que ficou pendente é que se eu envio 10:30 duas vezes, ele aceita e não entra no if pois a condição é IF AFTER 10:30. Agr se eu mando de 10:31 até 10:59 cai no if. Se tiver alguma dica, ficarei grato!

Comment: @Crane Você pode trocar o `if (after 10:30)` para `if  (!(before 10:30))` (se **não** é antes de 10:30, ou seja, se é "depois **ou** igual a 10:30")

Comment: Perfeito cara! Resolveu! Muito obgd mais uma vez. Eu achei q o after tivesse o msm efeito do !before. Mas o after equivale a só o > e o !berofe a >=.